# Navigation bar title updates too late (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have a tableViewController showing after a cell of a collectionViewController displaying some categories is selected (both inside a navigationViewController). I want the navigation bar to show the title of the selected category, but the title doesn't update in time.

This means whenever I go back and select a different category, it shows the old title, i.e. the title always lags on view behind?

This is my code in the collectionViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "CategorySelected") {
        let vc = segue.destination as! SearchOrgTableViewController
        vc.category = selectedCategory
    }
}
```

and in the TableViewController:

```
var category: CategoryModel?{
    didSet{
        guard let name = category?.name else{
            return
        }
        self.navigationItem.title = name
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix that?

I tried to set the title directly in the prepare function with the same result, calling reloadInputViews() also didn't work.

Comment: you can put that when segueing `vc.title =  category.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if (segue.identifier == "CategorySelected") {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
let vc = segue.destination as! SearchOrgTableViewController
    vc.category = selectedCategory
    vc.title = category.name } }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this did the job!

Answer (score 0):

> In iOS 10, UIKit has updated and unified background management for
>   UINavigationBar, UITabBar, and UIToolbar. In particular, changes to
>   background properties of these views (such as background or shadow
>   images, or setting the bar style) may kick off a layout pass for the
>   bar to resolve the new background appearance. In particular, this
>   means that attempts to change the background appearance of these bars
>   inside of -[UIView layoutSubviews], -[UIView updateConstraints],
>   -[UIViewController willLayoutSubviews], -[UIViewController didLayoutSubviews], - [UIViewController updateViewConstraints], or any
>   other method that is called in response to layout may result in a
>   layout loop.

so, this will happens.try to update title in view did load or view did appear may it will help you .